# Перебор Object.keys, потеря объектов на выходе

Tags: javascript

Передаю в функцию json файл c 4 объектами на выход получаю только 3 внутри функции все 4 объекта. Куда теряется 2 объект?

```
function goRec(obj) {
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
       var val = obj[key];
   });
   return val;
}
```

Структура json

```
        "0": {
         //данные
        },
        "44444": {
           //данные
        }, 
         "555555": {
           //данные
        },
         "777777": {
           //данные
        }
```

Comment: Как Вы определили, что что-то потерялось? Я думаю, в данном случае, можно было бы добавить воспроизводимый код

Comment: мне больше интерестно чего вы пытаетесь добиться таким кодом ?

Comment: А мне вообще интересно, как оно работает о_О. Данный пример кода не должен работать, а должен бросать ошибку `val is not defined`

Comment: Либо код неполный, либо он не имеет смысла